# Links jumping on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking at my CSS too long and need another set of eyes. I'm having trouble with a couple things. First: I can't figure out why my links are jumping on hover. It's supposed to be a mobile responsive hamburger to horizontal nav bar but I'm fairly new to this and have played around with too many parts of the code to know what I'm doing or not doing. Any help is appreciated!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

 <style>
body {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffffff;
 background-color: black;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }

header {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 position: fixed;
 height: 4em;
 line-height: 4em;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 1em;
 border-bottom: .1em solid #dddddd;
  }
h2 {
 font-size: 2.1em;
  }
p {
 font-size: 10em;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 1em;
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 319px) {

 .menu {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3.3em;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    border-top: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }   

  .menu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
  }

  .menu li:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #585858;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
      cursor: crosshair;
  }

  .menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

  .menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }

  #nav-icon4 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -47px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: cell;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: darkred;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 2;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px;
     -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
    -o-transform-origin: left center;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #nav-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 25px;
    left: 6px;
  }   
  }


@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {   
     h2 {
      z-index: 1000000;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      }

        p {
            font-size: 20em;
            color: white;
            padding-top: 1em;
  }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
.menu ul {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
.menu li {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    }
.menu li:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#nav-icon4 {
    display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 922px) {
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 18px;

    }
.menu {
    padding-right: 1px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 1400px) {
    header {
       height: 5em;
      line-height: 5em;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.6em;    
    }
    li {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .menu {
        padding-right: 1px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

    </style>

 <title>hamburgers</title>
 </head>

 <body>
     <header>

      <span>Shine Design</span>
      <div id="nav-icon4">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
      </div>

     </header>

     <div class="menu">
      <ul>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK ONE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK TWO</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK THREE</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FOUR</li>
       </a>
       <a href="#">
        <li>LINK FIVE</li>
       </a>
      </ul>
     </div>

   </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#nav-icon4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
    </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: can you create a working copy?

Comment: https://codepen.io/sshine2/pen/VbjGaE   The format is off and the bug isn't showing up in it though.  But the jumping links are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to line 237 and change this:

```
.menu li:hover {
cursor: crosshair;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 1em;
```

}

to this

```
.menu li:hover {
cursor: crosshair;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
padding-right: 0em;
padding-left: 0em;
```

}